# What do I call doing something complex without writing/visual help?

Tags: phrase-requests

What do I call the process of doing something without any visual help or writing? Example sentence:

> "He's such a brilliant student! He can calculate derivatives ____ whereas his classmates have to write down all the steps in their notebooks."

What should I put in ____. I've thought about "in memory"/"in mind" but it doesn't sound ok to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Idiomatically,

> [*The best programs we have could not break the encryption but you are saying he can **do it in his head**?*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The%20best%20programs%20we%20have%20could%20not%20break%20the%20encryption%20but%20you%20are%20saying%20he%20can%20do%20it%20in%20his%20head%3F%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/head) Phrases, definition 29 (heads up @Julie Carter)...

> **in one's head** *- by mental process without use of physical aids*

i.e. - *without needing to use a pencil and paper for complex calculations.*

Comment: I was about to post the same answer, then saw yours. Here is a definition from the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/head)  (phrase 29, under 'head') for 'in one's head', if you'd like to add it:)

Comment: By the way, can I say "I've calculated this in head" or do I have to use "in MY head"?

Comment: @Julie: Thanks for that link! I did search for a definition, but all I came up with was [this Oxford Learner Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-portuguese/to-do-something-in-one's-head) translation into Portugese! Richard - I think you always need a possessive pronoun for this idiomatic usage.

Comment: Yvw @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to [mental](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mental) calculation:

> - Executed or performed by the mind; existing in the mind: mental calculations.

[Mental calculation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_calculation):

> - ***comprises arithmetical calculations using only the human brain, with no help from calculators, computers, or pen and paper.*** People use mental calculation when computing tools are not available, when it is faster than other means of calculation (for example, conventional methods as taught in educational institutions), or in a competitive context. Mental calculation often involves the use of specific techniques devised for specific types of problems. (Wikipedia)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calculate%20mentally%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalculate%20mentally%3B%2Cc0) *calculate mentally*

- What should I put (in mind), *what should I memorise.*

Comment: So you mean to use "mentally" in the sentence?

Comment: Even though I'm not a native speaker, "calculate mentally" sounded strange to me but e.g. this article uses this phrase (+ about 13000 google results for exact match) so I assume this is correct [Teaching children to calculate mentally](http://dera.ioe.ac.uk/778/1/735bbb0036bed2dcdb32de11c7435b55.pdf)

Comment: "In his head" is colloquial. One would hear the locution more often than see it on the page. If you combine the phrase with a colloquial verb, it beats "mentally" for frequency even in written works. (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(do+it+in+your+head)%2C(do+it+mentally)%2C(calculate+mentally)%2C(calculate+in+your+head)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28do%20it%20in%20your%20head%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28do%20it%20mentally%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28calculate%20mentally%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28calculate%20in%20your%20head%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Tim Romano: It's not *very* colloquial (that would be *I can do sums like that **standing on my head***). Here's a pretty scholarly text talking about the great mathematician Euler: [*Finally, in 1766, he lost his sight altogether, but his work continued unabated {he carried out the calculations **in his head**}*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7YhMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA113&dq=newton+calculations+%22in+his+head%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V1aZVZTtO8HV7Ab_9o-QAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=newton%20calculations%20%22in%20his%20head%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

"He's such a brilliant student! He can calculate derivatives ***on the fly*** whereas his classmates have to write down all the steps in their notebooks."